# CSS selector select by div class attributes

Tags: html, css-selectors, kimono

```
<div class="thumbnail-popular" style="background: url('http://images.gogoanime.tv/images/upload/Go!.Princess.Precure.full.1812487.jpg');"></div>
```

I am trying to get the url component of this div class but I seem to be unable to fetch that specific data in the div class.

I have looked into making use of attributes but my attempts have been unsuccessful so far.

Usage of this CSS selector is through Kimonolabs.

Comment: CSS is for styling. You can use jQuery to get the url of the background image if that's what you want.

Comment: How would CSS return anything for you to get?

Comment: Under the support section of Kimonolabs, it mentions it as a usage of CSS selectors, that's what I worked with. 

The program doesn't allow me to use jQuery but instead only allows me to filter data through CSS selector.

The link is https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203069324-Use-advanced-mode

Comment: What were the precise selectors that you attempted with?

Comment: @j08691: CSS wouldn't, but a selector certainly would - that's kinda what a selector is supposed to do. The OP specifically mentioned selectors here, though they erroneously tagged the question with [css].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div.thumbnail-popular` should get you the element you're looking for — unless there is more than one such element, in which case you will need to narrow down your selector.

For example you will need to find out if this particular element belongs to a specific parent, or is the first, second, ... nth child, or any other information about the surrounding elements in the page that you're working with.

The background URL is in a `style` attribute on this element, so you will need to extract that attribute as described [here](https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203302830-Extract-attributes-with-kimono). However you will still need to parse the declarations inside the `style` value in order to get the URL; I am not sure if it is possible to do this through kimono as I am not familiar with it (I'm not sure what its advanced mode really does, and it's difficult to tell from the lone screenshot that is provided in that help article).